# Sending email via Django gives me (_ssl.c:3895) error

Tags: python, django, ssl-certificate, django-email

It looks like there is a problem with the ssl certificate when trying to send emails using `django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend`.

```
Settings.py

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE = certifi.where()
EMAIL_SSL_CA_BUNDLE = certifi.where()
```

The password is an app password I created in my google account. I even tried to use third party services like Elastic Email and SendGrid, but it still gives me an error. Removing the `EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE` and `EMAIL_SSL_CA_BUNDLE` will then give me a (_ssl.c:997) error.

```
views.py

@api_view(["POST"])
def signupUser(request):
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

```
Serializers.py

import random

from user_api.models import CustomUser
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.core.mail import send_mail

from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'profile_image', 'api_key']
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}, 'id': {'read_only': True}}

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.username = validated_data['username']
        instance.email = validated_data['email']
        instance.api_key = validated_data['api_key']
        instance.profile_image = validated_data['profile_image']

        instance.save()
        return instance

    def create(self, validated_data):
        verification_code = random.randint(100000, 999999)
        user = CustomUser.objects.create(username=validated_data['username'],email=validated_data['email'], password=make_password(validated_data['password']), verification_code=verification_code)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        email = EmailMessage(
            'Hello',
            f'This is your verification code : {verification_code}',
            'email@gmail.com',
            [validated_data['email']]
        )

        email.fail_silently=False
        email.send()
        
        return user
```

I also tried switching the `EMAIL_BACKEND` to `django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend`.
It works well and I see the email being logged in the console.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to using `TLS` instead of `SSL`, or could be caused by incorrect handling of the `SSL` certificates.

First we try with `TLS`, by changing your `EMAIL_USE_TLS` setting to `False` and set `EMAIL_USE_SSL` to `True`. Also, change `EMAIL_PORT` to 465

Or we could remove the `EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE` and `EMAIL_SSL_CA_BUNDLE`, your email settings should be like that:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: I changed my settings to what you provided and it gives me a (_ssl.c:997) error.

Comment: Gmail must be blocking the sign-in attempt because it considers it to be suspicious, check https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps, https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha  and if you have 2 step verification https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

Comment: It looks like I have 2 step verification, in fact google won't let you make app passwords without it. I tried on my other account and it still gives me the same error.